# How do I send an audio file from a url?,telebot

Tags: telebot

When sending an audio file to a user it sends an empty file? Why

```py
import requests

url = "https://rr2---sn-o5f54xui5ai5qi5g5-nq5e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1663630447&ei=D6goY5PcDJjwhgbypLNQ&ip=192.99.200.82&id=o-APi3v7YxiltNGhuudEU1QadeZGu43KlVFs9Xzj8cG52L&itag=249&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&vprv=1&mime=audio%2Fwebm&ns=EI4wJnvmPdR_yWihy94GX_YI&gir=yes&clen=1087015&dur=155.621&lmt=1636322375228392&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373,24007246&c=WEB&rbqsm=fr&txp=5432434&n=vJaFhab1gWN74MHA&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Citag%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRAIgT5oP8aspSaeYQrHoI2xFwz4tA_1unBjxWArhIqRXI5UCIDxQkV9PN3DtA3QNtPKXLvKR0DGpoh9qAk5OzHU5JgjN&redirect_counter=1&rm=sn-t0al7s&req_id=dfa7083a5931a3ee&cms_redirect=yes&ipbypass=yes&mh=XX&mip=37.239.52.22&mm=31&mn=sn-o5f54xui5ai5qi5g5-nq5e&ms=au&mt=1663608542&mv=m&mvi=2&pl=24&lsparams=ipbypass,mh,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgGkeAL7toNeXZOgbrYyb0TkqKj593EfhIp269a_YFoAQCIQCtdiY5Z5YKkY6q4qRAUBfQJ2gN5ybZWMYDeg3PG2Kb9g%3D%3D"

files = {'audio': DataAudio}                
payload = {
            'chat_id': "1395609507",
                'title': "jj",
                'parse_mode': 'HTML',
                'performer': 'YouTube'                              
                }   
                                
resp = requests.post(
        "https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendAudio".format(token="xxxxxxxxx"),
        data=payload,
        files=files).json() 
print(resp)
```

I used this but it doesn't send the audio file !

> bot.send_voice(message.chat.id,url)

I hope you have a solution

- Uncle the audio link used is from Youtube

Answer (score 1):

you should use send_audio
https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html?highlight=audio#telebot.TeleBot.send_audio

also first save it then send that will be more smooth